# Действие по нажатию на ListView

Tags: android

```
public void test() {
    string name [] = { "1","2"};
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, name);
    lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
}

protected void onListItemClick(ListView l, View v, int position, long id) {
    String item = (String) getListAdapter().getItem(position);
    Toast.makeText(this, item + " выбран", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
}
```

Это действие по нажатию на один из элементов `listView`, жалуется на  `getListAdapter()`:

> The method getListAdapter() is undefined for the type MainActivity

Comment: тут тоже все правильно, такого метода просто нету в классе MainActivity

Comment: Как его добавить?

Comment: Спасибо,а нет ли у тебя icq и пару секунд свободного времени на ответа на такие глупые вопросы

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
public void test() {
    string name [] = { "1","2"};
    ListView lvMain = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listView1);
    ArrayAdapter<String> adapter = new ArrayAdapter<String>(this,
    R.layout.rowlayout, R.id.label, name);

lvMain.setOnItemClickListener(new onItemClickListener(){
   @Override
    public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> a, View v,int position, long id) 
    {
        Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(), "Click " + position, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

    }
});
   lvMain.setAdapter(adapter);
}
```